# Optional trait's method: call empty method or skip it at all?

Tags: rust, methods, option-type, traits

If I have an optional method that has to be called many many times what is better if I want to skip it: have an empty body and call it or check the **bool/Option** before calling it?

The following benchmark make no sense. It gave zeroes.

```rust
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;

trait OptTrait: 'static {
    fn cheap_call(&mut self, data: u8);
    fn expensive_call(&mut self, data: u8);
}

type ExpensiveFnOf<T> = &'static dyn Fn(&mut T, u8);

struct Container<T: OptTrait> {
    inner: T,
    expensive_fn: Option<ExpensiveFnOf<T>>,
}

impl<T: OptTrait> Container<T> {
    fn new(inner: T, expensive: bool) -> Self {
        let expensive_fn = {
            if expensive {
                Some(&T::expensive_call as ExpensiveFnOf<T>)
            } else {
                None
            }
        };
        Self {
            inner,
            expensive_fn,
        }
    }
}

struct MyStruct;

impl OptTrait for MyStruct {
    fn cheap_call(&mut self, _data: u8) {
    }
    fn expensive_call(&mut self, _data: u8) {
    }
}


#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use test::Bencher;

    #[bench]
    fn bench_always_call_empty(b: &mut Bencher) {
        let mut cont = Container::new(MyStruct, false);
        b.iter(|| {
            cont.inner.cheap_call(0);
            cont.inner.expensive_call(1);
        });
    }

    #[bench]
    fn bench_alwaws_skip_empty(b: &mut Bencher) {
        let mut cont = Container::new(MyStruct, false);
        b.iter(|| {
            cont.inner.cheap_call(0);
            if let Some(func) = cont.expensive_fn {
                func(&mut cont.inner, 1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler will remove the calls to empty functions. That's why, when benchmarking, you'd better have a side effect, for example return a value from your functions and sending those functions to a blackhole (see [there](https://docs.rs/glassbench/0.3.0/src/glassbench/black_box.rs.html#11-17))

Comment: But you can't really benchmark cases so virtual they contain nothing. You should benchmark the real stuff, with and without the suspected optimization. Remember that the compiler will seize any possible opportunity to do the work for you.